# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -laravel 8

Tags: laravel

**That's my controller:**

```
public function index($slug_categoryName){

    $categories=Categories::where('slug' ,$slug_categoryName)->firstOrFail();
    $lower_categories=Categories::where('top_id', $categories->id)->get();

    $products=$categories->products;

   return view('category' ,compact('categories' ,'lower_categories' ,'products'));
}
```

**My blade file:**

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
 <h5><a class="ps-product__name" href="product-default.html">{{ $product->product_name }}</a></h5>
@endforeach
```

**my products Model**

```
    public function products(){
    return $this ->balongsToMany('App\Models\Products' , 'category_products');
}
```

**my categories model**

```
   public function categories(){
    return $this ->balongsToMany('App\Models\Categories' , 'category_products');
}
```

**when I save and refresh the page I get an error--->**
*Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp\www\BootcampProject\resources\views\category.blade.php)*

Comment: Check the variable `$products` after `$products = $category-> products;`  it should not be empty

Comment: and add `@if (count($products))` before your loop.This will avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because some `$categories` may not have `products` when you call `$categories->products`
In you blade file put this instead:

```
@if($products)
    @foreach ($products as $product)
     <h5><a class="ps-product__name" href="product-default.html">{{ $product->product_name }}</a></h5>
    @endforeach
@endif
```